# VS Code: how to restore git settings for new laptop

Tags: visual-studio-code

after I got myself a new laptop, I have transferred my source files of a vue project from my previous laptop to my new one.

However, on my new laptop, the git seems not be working properly on VS code.

Each time when I open a file, a new item is showing under "Source Control Providers". Please check the attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

However, when I commit the change and push them to github, it works.

My version of VS code is: Version 1.19.1 Commit 0759f77bb8d86658bc935a10a64f6182c5a1eeba Date 2017-12-19T09:46:23.884Z Shell 1.7.9 Renderer 58.0.3029.110 Node 7.9.0 Architecture x64.

Sorry I am new in git. Maybe this has something to do with my local repository?

Comment: Is the problem restricted to Visual Studio Code? Git works fine elsewhere?

Comment: That's a pretty old version of VS Code. Why don't you update it?